# How to use :after to rotate arrow as I want

Tags: html, css

I have a little issue.
I need to get image like bellow but can't set arrow as I want but I think that I am close :)
http://jsfiddle.net/LDhLv/

```
.d:after {
    content: "";
position: absolute;
width: 0;
height: 0;
bottom: 95%;
left: 100px;
border-left: 10px solid #666;
border-right: 10px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
border-top: 0px solid transparent;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

CSS:

```
.d{border:1px solid #666; background: #fff; width:100px; height:50px; margin:60px;position:relative}
.d:before, .d:after{
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;    
}
.d:before {
    top: -10px;
    right: -1px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #666;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}

.d:after {
    top: -8px;
    right: 0px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;    
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/wW47b/)

I've tweaked the `top/bottom` `left/right` positioning for a more stable position, relative to the parent element. Also, I created the arrow in such a way that no rotation is necessary.

Comment: Thanks can you maybe show me how to make it like on image white inside and borders some other color?

Comment: I know how to set border on box but can't set border on that little corner.

Comment: That's a little difficult because essentially, that is what the corner is; borders. I'm going to take a look at [cssarrowplease.com](http://cssarrowplease.com/) (might be a good idea to check it out too) and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 1):

Change `border-left: 10px solid #666` to `border-left: 10px solid transparent`.. and `border-top: 0px solid transparent` to `border-top: 10px solid transparent`.

To change shape of the triangle, set `0px` on `border-right` or just remove it completely.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/zfH8j/)

```
.d:after {
    content: "\A";
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 90px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #666; 
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;    
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the right border and the rest is just position

```
.d:after {
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    bottom: 40px;
    left:80px;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid #666;   
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;    
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

See modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LDhLv/3/)